# What is the difference between the 1st and 2nd NCOPs for Symphogear (season one)?

Tags: senki-zesshou-symphogear

The BDs for Symphogear (season one) came with three creditless versions of the OP (Synchrogazer). One difference between the second and third versions of the OP (I think the only difference, in fact) is that Yukine is added to [this shot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/83K53.jpg), which makes sense, since the third version of the OP is first used in episode 11, by which point Yukine is one of the "good guys".

But I cannot, for the life of me, tell what the difference between the first and second versions of the OP is. I even played them side-by-side, and still couldn't notice anything different between them. How do the first and second versions differ?

Comment: Did you by chance look at the accompanying music? Sometimes they just tweak that a bit.

Comment: Doesn't seem like the music changed; both sound identical (aside from encoding artifacts, I guess) to each other and to the 3rd NCOP.

Answer (score 3):

I ended up going through the OP with a fine-toothed framestepper, whereupon I finally sighted the differences between the two.

At 00:51-00:52, NCOP 1 has a body shot of Yukine in Nehushtan, followed by a face shot of Yukine in Nehushtan...

[image: Yukine in Nehushtan, body]
[image: Yukine in Nehushtan, face]

...while in NCOP 2, there's a body shot of *Finé* in Nehushtan, followed by a face shot of Yukine in *Ichaival*.

[image: Finé in Nehushtan, body]
[image: Yukine in Ichaival, face]

The shots last for 8 and 10 frames, respectively.

(And one's probably traced off of the other, so they look pretty similar if you're not specifically looking for them as they flash by, which is why it took me a while to notice. Unexciting answer, but it is what it is.)